# What is the error within the ARM template? Please advise

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

Hello I am trying to deploy this template via azure devops and get this error:

'The template resource '' of type 'microsoft.insights/workbooks' at line '1' and column '1512' is not valid. The name property cannot be null or empty. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'." AdditionalInfo=[{"info":{"lineNumber":1,"linePosition":1512,"path":"properties.template.resources[0]"},"type":"TemplateViolation"}]

Template:

```
{
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "workbookDisplayName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Azure Firewall Workbook",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The friendly name for the workbook that is used in the Gallery or Saved List.  This name must be unique within a resource group."
        }
      },
      "workbookType": {
        "type": "string",
        "allowedValues": [
            "workbook",
            "sentinel"
            
          ],
          "defaultValue": "workbook",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The gallery that the workbook will been shown under. Supported values include workbook, tsg, etc. Usually, this is 'workbook'"
        }
      },
      "DiagnosticsWorkspaceName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "WorkspaceName",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Provide the workspace name for your Network Diagnostic logs"
        }
      },
      "DiagnosticsWorkspaceSubscription": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "WorkspaceSubscriptionID",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Provide the workspace subscription GUID for your Network Diagnostic logs"
        }
      },
      "DiagnosticsWorkspaceResourceGroup": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "ResourceGroupName",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Provide the workspace resourcegroupname for your Network Diagnostic logs"
        }
      },
      "workbookId": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[newGuid()]",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The unique guid for this workbook instance"
        }
      }
    },
    "variables": {
            "workbookSourceId": "[concat('/subscriptions/',parameters('DiagnosticsWorkspaceSubscription'),'/resourcegroups/', parameters('DiagnosticsWorkspaceResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/',parameters('DiagnosticsWorkspaceName'))]"
  },
    "resources": [
      {
        "name": "[parameters('workbookId')]",
        "type": "microsoft.insights/workbooks",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-17-preview",
        "dependsOn": [],
        "kind": "shared",
        "properties": {
          "displayName": "[parameters('workbookDisplayName')]"}",
          "version": "1.0",
          "sourceId": "[variables('workbookSourceId')]",
          "category": "[parameters('workbookType')]"
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputs": {
      "workbookId": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[resourceId( 'microsoft.insights/workbooks', parameters('workbookId'))]"
      }
    },
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#"
  }
```

Comment: Hi Hope sull, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I hope you found VenkateshDodda-MT's answer useful; I really recommend using tools like the [Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msazurermtools.azurerm-vscode-tools) extension for VS Code; I use it too, and it really helps. The time saved avoiding little syntax errors like this is invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are some syntactical errors in the above shared ARM template .

> ```
>  "properties": {
>           "displayName": "[parameters('workbookDisplayName')]"}",
>           "version": "1.0",
>           "sourceId": "[variables('workbookSourceId')]",
>           "category": "[parameters('workbookType')]"
>         }
> ```

As per the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/workbooks?tabs=json#template-format) for the `Microsoft.Insights/Workbooks` sourceID,Category & Version are the parameters of the properties block.

When we have loaded the above shared Json template/ARM template in our VisualStudioCode,the intellisense has found few syntactical errors & also thrown error stating  `serializedData` parameter is mandatory in the properities block of `Microsoft.Insights/Workbooks`.

**Here is the ARM template post fixing those errors** & tried deploying in our local environment which got successfully deployed without any issues.

```html
{
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "workbookDisplayName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Azure Firewall Workbook",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The friendly name for the workbook that is used in the Gallery or Saved List.  This name must be unique within a resource group."
        }
      },
      "workbookType": {
        "type": "string",
        "allowedValues": [
            "workbook",
            "sentinel"
            
          ],
          "defaultValue": "workbook",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The gallery that the workbook will been shown under. Supported values include workbook, tsg, etc. Usually, this is 'workbook'"
        }
      },
      "DiagnosticsWorkspaceName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "WorkspaceName",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Provide the workspace name for your Network Diagnostic logs"
        }
      },
      "DiagnosticsWorkspaceSubscription": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "WorkspaceSubscriptionID",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Provide the workspace subscription GUID for your Network Diagnostic logs"
        }
      },
      "DiagnosticsWorkspaceResourceGroup": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "ResourceGroupName",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Provide the workspace resourcegroupname for your Network Diagnostic logs"
        }
      },
      "workbookId": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[newGuid()]",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The unique guid for this workbook instance"
        }
      }
    },
    "variables": {
            "workbookSourceId": "[concat('/subscriptions/',parameters('DiagnosticsWorkspaceSubscription'),'/resourcegroups/', parameters('DiagnosticsWorkspaceResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/',parameters('DiagnosticsWorkspaceName'))]"
  },
    "resources": [
      {
        "name": "[parameters('workbookId')]",
        "type": "microsoft.insights/workbooks",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-17-preview",
        "dependsOn": [],
        "kind": "shared",
        "properties" : {
        "displayName": "[parameters('workbookDisplayName')]",
          "sourceId": "[variables('workbookSourceId')]",
          "category": "[parameters('workbookType')]",
            "serializedData" : "",
            "version" : "1.0"
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputs": {
      "workbookId": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[resourceId( 'microsoft.insights/workbooks', parameters('workbookId'))]"
      }
    },
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#"
}
```

**Note:**
In the above shared template, we observed that the schema version in the deployment template  you are using is `2015-01-01` its always suggested to use latest version `2019-04-01`

**Here is the output sample for our reference:**

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you